# Extract features from images with a pre-trained CNN model in Keras

Tags: computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I have a simple CNN model which looks like this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1179776   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,199,882.0
Trainable params: 1,199,882.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I've popped dense_2 (softmax layer) and dropout_2 layers to extract features from images:

(i'm using a custom pop function proposed here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2640)

```
def pop_layer(model):
    if not model.outputs:
        raise Exception('Sequential model cannot be popped: model is empty.')

    model.layers.pop()
    if not model.layers:
        model.outputs = []
        model.inbound_nodes = []
        model.outbound_nodes = []
    else:
        model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
        model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
    model.built = False
```

Popping the two  last layers:

```
pop_layer(model)
pop_layer(model)
```

after that doing `model.summary()`:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1179776   
=================================================================
Total params: 1,198,592.0
Trainable params: 1,198,592.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The two last layers were popped from the model, but when i'm doing the predictions:

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
print(len(predictions[0]))

10
```

As you can see the output is still the softmax, is something that i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you show us `print(predictions.shape)`?

Comment: Sure, `(10000, 10)`. Thanks

Comment: Could you try `model.pop()` twice instead your function?

Comment: Same result, it seems that when you are doing the predictions keras uses the full model

Comment: Try `model.build()` after poping.

Comment: Okaay, i was missing the build.... Now it works! Thank you!!!

Comment: If you don't mind I would also cherrish the upvote of my answer :)

Comment: Okay no problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that you need to `build` or `compile` model after you `pop` layers in order to make your model working.